# Unable to launch cqlsh in datastax Cassandra distribution

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have donwloaded ddac-5.1.17, and can successfully launch cassandra server.

But on executing 'cqlsh' command from command line in Windows 10, I get strange error:

> \ddac-5.1.17\bin>cqlsh
>
> File "....\ddac-5.1.17\bin\cqlsh.py", line 152
>       except ImportError, e:
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What's wrong here?

Comment: Wich Python version are you using ?

Comment: Its Python 3.7.4

Comment: Try to downgrading to python 2.7, in the requirements page, it says python 2.7.x, I am pretty sure it is a python version issue

Answer (score 0):

Use python 2.7,

You can find detail here

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10190

I hope this helps !